# how to insert onclick attribute into a span?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fetching items from an API and creating a list in the web-client. I need to add onclick in the span-element where the text strings should reside in order to call a script when the user clicks on it. I can't seem to insert the onlick attribute into the span-element.

HTML:

```
   <ul id="list">
        </ul>
```

Javascript:

```js
array= array of strings fetched from api.

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) { 
    var string=array[i].text;
    var list= document.createElement("li");
    var span=document.createElement("SPAN");
    span.onclick="call()"; 
    var txt_node=document.createTextNode(string);
    span.appendChild(txt_node)
    list.appendChild(span);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(list);
}
```

is there an alternative way of making the span object clickable?

Comment: You can use `span.onclick=call;`

Comment: `<span>` elements are not designed to be interactive, they won't get the focus and (for example) screen readers won't announce them as interactive. Use a `<button>` instead. Apply CSS if you don't like the default look.

Comment: `span.addEventListener('click', call)`, or `document.querySelector('#list').addEventListener('click', call)` (and then use the `event.target` property of the Event Object inside the `call()` function); but do remember Quentin's advice regarding usability.